# TP-LINK MR3020 wireless setup on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless

I`m very much new this Ubuntu planet, just trying to out of Windows planet...

Indeed, ubuntu is working great and easy to install.But I was unhappy on configuring wireless router setup. I`ve TP-LINK MR3020 router but unable to use with ubuntu.

Please help on setup/router config. Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can configure the router with going to `192.168.0.254` in you web browser. that should work just as well in linux as on windows. Enter the default User Name and Password: admin. according to the manual...